# Django & Multiple Forms

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to work out the most django-reffic way to do the following:

**Models**

```
class Warehouse(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()

class Product(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()

class ProductStock(models.Model):
      product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
      warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse)
      qty = models.IntegerField()
```

What would be the best way to build the forms on the product page knowing that I need to enter the stock for each warehouse?

I know I could just grab the warehouses and iterate over them and build a qty field input then iterate over that on submission, but is there a better way?

Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Modelformsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) should do the trick. In particular, look into inline modelformsets and inlineformset_factory. They are one of my favourite things in Django, but also a big gnarly if you're a newcomer to the framework.

Comment: how would I limit it for only the product i'm entering stock for on creation?